# Object.assign() creates wierd properties when assigns mongoose doc

Tags: node.js, mongoose, assign

```
MessageThread.findById(req.body._id)
      .populate({ path: "messages" })
      .exec((err, foundMessageThread) => {
        var filtered = foundMessageThread.messages.map(message=>{
          return Object.assign({}, message, {isRead: true});
        })
        console.log("filtered", filtered);

      });
```

console.log shows:

```
{ '$__':
 InternalCache {
   strictMode: true,
   selected: {},
   shardval: undefined,
   saveError: undefined,
   validationError: undefined,
   adhocPaths: undefined,
   removing: undefined,
   inserting: undefined,
   version: undefined,
   getters: {},
   _id: 5a4c7f2d8b49fc260c396f55,
   populate: undefined,
   populated: undefined,
   wasPopulated: true,
   scope: undefined,
   activePaths: [Object],
   pathsToScopes: {},
   ownerDocument: undefined,
   fullPath: undefined,
   emitter: [Object],
   '$options': true },
isNew: false,
errors: undefined,
_doc:
 { sentAt: 2018-01-03T06:58:53.188Z,
   isRead: false,
   _id: 5a4c7f2d8b49fc260c396f55,
   sender: 5a4b77767251b44cd870219f,
   reciever: 5a4b780a7251b44cd87021a1,
   text: 'qwe',
   __v: 0 },
'$init': true,
isRead: true },
......
```

it repeats many times.
I suppose it (InternalCache { strictMode: true...) relates to **message** that is taken from **foundMessageThread**. And it reveals its metadata(in my term) while assigning. Because:

```
MessageThread.findById(req.body._id)
  .populate({ path: "messages" })
  .exec((err, foundMessageThread) => {
    var filtered = foundMessageThread.messages.map(message=>{
      console.log("message", message)
      return Object.assign({}, message, {isRead: true});
    })
    console.log("filtered", filtered);

  });
```

console.log shows

```
{ sentAt: 2018-01-03T06:58:53.188Z,
  isRead: false,
  _id: 5a4c7f2d8b49fc260c396f55,
  sender: 5a4b77767251b44cd870219f,
  reciever: 5a4b780a7251b44cd87021a1,
  text: 'qwe',
  __v: 0 },
....
```

**My question:**

1. Is it normal behavior?
2. If it is how to fix it? Because "metadata" prevents objects being assigned.

P.S. I've tried:

```
MessageThread.findById(req.body._id)
  .populate({ path: "messages" })
  .exec((err, foundMessageThread) => {
    var filtered = foundMessageThread.messages.map(message=>{
      return **Object.assign({}, message._doc, {isRead: true})**;
    })
    console.log("filtered", filtered);

  });
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a normal behaviour with mongoose. Objects returned by mongoose wrap the actual data, so as to add behaviours (methods) to it.

You can get to the actual data object by using `toObject` method, for eg, `message.toObject()`.

However there are properties like `__v`, which are used by mongoose for house keeping purposes. If you don't want them, you can modify the `toObject` method like this

```
messageSchema.set('toObject', {
  versionKey: false,
  transform: (doc, ret) => {
    delete ret.__v;
    return ret;
  },
});
```

Comment: Thanks @AkshendraPratap. But why when I do `Object.assign()` it shows up, when I do `console.log()` it doesn't. For example,  in the 3rd code above `console.log("message")` showed regular doc. but when I did `Object.assign()`, actual data pop out? ))

Comment: On a very higher level, to print the object as string, `console.log` will use a `toString()` function. Mongoose provides a `toString` for its documents as helper. Which is basically retuning `toObject`. You can look at the code here, https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/2e70892bcd4932c7ab0420085e1b9f35da98a263/lib/document.js

Answer (score 4):

You can also use `.lean()` method with mongoose request. This allows to get less cumbersome response and process it easyly:

```
try {
    const assets = await myModel.Assets
      .find({ isActive: true }, { __v: 0, _id: 0 })
      .lean()
      .exec()
    // do something
}
catch(error) {
  throw error
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the `_doc` property of mongoose objects should be referenced if you want to either assign to or from those objects.  In fact, I was unable to set additional properties in a normal manner like so `mongoDoc.newProp = propValue;`.  It was not altering the original object.

For assignment, instead of:

`Object.assign(mongoDoc, {a: 1, b: 2});`

You'd want:

`Object.assign(mongoDoc._doc, {a: 1, b: 2});`

Or if you're assigning the mongoDoc properties to another object, you'd want

`Object.assign({a: 1, b: 2}, mongoDoc._doc);`

Comment: that works but it does not look like a clean way to me!

Answer (score 0):

// add .lean() in your query like below

```
const documents = await DocumentModel.find().lean();

// at debug now ,
// now you will get your result;
```